# Meaning of いやみを必ず顔に表す

Tags: meaning, syntax

What does this line mean?
いやみを必ず顔に表す

I know the individual words but I can't seem to figure out the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you recognise each of the words "[顔]{かお}" and "[表]{あらわ}す", don't you?
"顔に表す" is a phrase which means that someone shows his feelings on his face obviously.

So, this sentence denotes, "The speaker never fails to show his sarcasm on his face."